# Accessing a templated nested struct from a static function

Tags: c++, templates, nested

I have the following class, in which I am trying to define a nested template struct:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    // MyClass();
    //~MyClass();

    template <class T>
    struct Arguments
    {
        T* m_obj;
    };


private:
    template <typename T>
    static void S_Func (void* _arguments); 
};
```

Accessing it from a regular member function seems to compile fine:

```
Arguments<T>* args = new Arguments<T>;
```

But when I try to access it from a static function like this:

```
template <typename T>
void MyClass::S_Func (void* _arguments)
{
    MyClass::struct Arguments<T>* args = (MyClass::struct Arguments<T>*)(_arguments); 
    T* obj = args->m_obj;
}
```

I get the following error:

expected unqualified-id before ‘struct’
  MyClass::struct Arguments* args = (MyClass::struct Arguments*)(_argument

How do I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Replace `MyClass::struct Arguments<T>* args = (MyClass::struct Arguments<T>*)(_arguments);` with `MyClass::Arguments<T>* args = (MyClass::Arguments<T>*)(_arguments);`

Comment: Thanks! how come you don't need the struct? it did not allow me to typedef..

Comment: You don't need to `typedef` structs in c++.

Comment: That is one place c++ is different than c.